# Verion 9 of Highlight.js has reached EOL. It will no longer be supported

Tags: npm, error-handling, highlight

err:
Verion 9 of Highlight.js has reached EOL.  It will no longer
be supported or receive security updates in the future.
Please upgrade to version 10 or encourage your indirect
dependencies to do so.

How do I change the version? And what is Highlight.js for?
thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same message when I ran the *typemorm:run*....

I tried to find some answer but found nothing. The only thing I found was an issue saying to upgrade highlight to version 10+ (https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2877).

So, I looked into my code to see where it was using the highligh.js with *npm ls highligh.js* and then navigate into the folder and upgrade manually the highligh.js with *npm i highligh.js*.

I hope to have helped you in something.

Comment: Oh I almost forgot it, I had to upgrade the cli-highlight dependency in the typeorm too.

Comment: Thank you for your response